# Using custom pushpins in my Windows 8.1 XAML app using Bing Maps SDK

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps

In my C++/XAML Windows 8.1 app, I want to use a pushpin to denote a location that the user has selected.  The default pushpin is very limited and it doesn't even show all the text I add to the "Text" field of the pushpin.

I really want to show something similar to the default pushpin and under that a textblock with some text.

So I think I have to create a user control and use it as a custom pushpin.  However, when I do this the "custom pushpin" doesn't appear on the map at the same location that the user selected.  It feels like in order to get it at the same location, I need to get the margins of the user control right through hit and trial.  What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I haven't used that SDK, but I would imagine you would need to supply your own `DataTemplate` to use for a pushpin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a little more, I was able to specify the correct position of the custom pushpin using the following API:

Bing::Maps::MapLayer::SetPositionAnchor(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject^, Windows::Foundation::Point)

See the [API reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846488.aspx).